# Code Running but not running on scene reload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button in my game that leaves the game and loads out to the main menu scene.

Everything works fine going into the game the first time. When I try to reload back in the code appears to be running but nothing is going on. I have put `Debug.Logs` all through the code trying to find a point where it stops because I am not getting any error codes. All the `Debug.Logs` are logged to the console. I have a panel that switches `Color.lerp` to another color. I put a `Debug.log` inside that lerp update and that never stops being logged. The color of the panel never changes in the player, the debug is repeating over and over and yet when I select the panel in the scene while the game is playing the image color is the desired color in the inspector.

When I finish the game, I have a play again button. This button simply reloads the scene, and with that, everything works fine.

I am using PhotonNetwork, I have noticed that in multiplayer I can leave the match and then rejoin another room and everything works fine as well. this bug only seems to happen when I have PhotonNetwork.offlineMode = true. I go into the scene for the first match and everything works fine, but when I leave that offline match shit don't work right, I can reload the offline mode match and everything still works. It appears that when I leave the offline room stuff goes astray and I have no idea why.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

public class SceneController {

```
public static void LoadStartMenu() {
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(0);
}

public static void LoadLobbyScene() {
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
}

public static void LoadGameScene() {
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(2);
}

public static void ReloadScene() {
    Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(scene.buildIndex);
}
```

}

that is the scene manager class.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you "reload back in"? Are you resetting the scene via the Scene Manager? Could you provide sample code, how you switch between the Menu and the Game scenes?

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the code associated with the error prone button differs from the "play again" button.